SQL Cumulative Total Grouped
I am trying to create a cumulative total for the Paid column (SUMPaid), grouped by Contract and Ordered by Year.

I tried using SUM with Partition By but that SUMs the group from the first line,
I tried using LAG + LAG(Paid,1) but that sums only the previous column which wont
work when there are 3 years in the contract (200662)
[Paid] + LAG([Paid],1) OVER (PARTITION BY Contract ORDER BY [Year])

Can anyone suggest how to do this ?

What's your expected result? SUM(Paid) OVER(PARTITION BY Contract ORDER BY Year) should be "correct", why isn't that working?

Please add source data sample as text.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.
